# UK Transit Visa, Application returned by courier before decision made

Tags: visas, uk, transit-visas

On August 24 my biometrics were collected at the Visa Application Center. On the 29th I received an email saying "Application Received by UK Visas & Immigration".

Until today I didn't receive any additional email, but this one:

[image]

On the other hand on the TLS site, in "Track my application" the timeline looks like:

Services Selected - done

Services paid - done

Application Submitted - done

Transferred for Decision - done

Received by UKVI - done

**Decision Made - not yet done**

**Ready for Courier Return - not yet done**

Dispatch by Courier - done

All this stuff confuses me... Does this mean that they made a decision and just didn't yet send an email? Does this mean that they just sent me back my passport and they yet have to make a decision?

P.S. I have a flight this Friday, is there any chance to get the visa on time? I applied for the visa in Moldova. Oh yeah, I also received this email two days ago:

[image]

Also, when I try to track using DHL's site it says: (Not found): No result found for your DHL query. Please try again.

Thanks,

Denis.

Comment: Did you reply to their email which was asking for documents?

Comment: Sure, in less than  1 hour I've sent them the bank statement for last 6 months and a photo of my booking confirmation. It's has been read one the same day 4 times and one more time the next day :) (thx Mailtrack, lol)

Comment: Then don't worry too much about the confusing status. Wait for your passport it will arrive with the decision. So many times I ve had passport in my hand with the visa where the online status still said pending decision

Comment: Good, right now I've received another email from DHL about the shipment, the estimated delivery is on Friday, I hope I'll know the decision till my flight at 10 p.m. Thank you very much!

Comment: P.S. I hope they decided to give me that Visa))

Comment: All the best :) next time apply a little earlier though ;)

Comment: Yeah, it is kind of my fault, didn't research the topic before applying for visa.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is okay, just 10 minutes ago received my  passport back and I got the Visa. On the TLS site the same timeline, no updates. Received the shipment 1 day earlier.

Comment: Great, enjoy your trip:)