# UK visa goes to VAC first or home directly?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK visa from Munich and opted for the courier service to deliver the passport to my home. I got the email on Friday (7th of June) that my UK visa application has been dispatched with no tracking number mentioned.

I want to understand if the visa will be sent to the visa office in Munich first, and then to me or if it will be directly couriered to me? I have to travel on Tuesday evening (11th of June) but not sure how can I get the visa on time. If it goes to the Munich office first, then should I go to munich office on Tuesday morning and collect it from there or should I wait for the courier at home?

Has anyone faced this kind of issue? Due to public holiday on Monday, I am not sure how I can get visa on time.

Answer (score 1):

I asked  friend who applied and got UK visa. UK Visa Immigration couriered her passport, visa back at her home directly like [EMRE ŞAHİN's case](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137853).

> [image]

[Postica Ðenis's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/102117) is same.

> [image]

But can you post exact words in UK Visa Immigration's email to you? Some other emails from UK Visa Immigration don't write out "couriered back to you" [like this email](https://visainfodesk.com/appreciation-post-2/).

> [image]